# 5V, ~3A - 18650 li-ion battery bundle charger/balancer

Tags: power-supply, power-control, power-bank

I have a 15600MAh battery pack that came in one of my devices. Long story short, the controller circuit that charges the batteries was fried in a power outage, but the batteries are still good. I have replaced the device they came in, but I was thinking about re-purposing the batteries for a DIY project. I have several Li-Ion/Li-Po battery balancing/charging circuits, but none of them are made for a configuration like this.
I need a good Li-Ion battery charging board for this battery pack, any ideas?

Here's a pic of the battery pack (I did not solder them together, they came like that):
[image]

I don't have a multi-meter capable of measuring Amps, but I estimate the batteries to put out a total of around 3A, and I get a voltage reading of about 4.5V.

Comment: To me it looks like they are all in parallel. Then I think you don't need a balancer and any charger which doesn't try to charge it too fast should work. But 4.5V is really strange, that's too much for one cell and too little for even two in series. I fear either it's overcharged or undercharged. But it can't really be two stages in series with 5 cells in total, so probably overcharged. Or another battery chemistry altogether.

Comment: I would suspect another battery chemistry.  One possibility is, 5 NiCD cells in serial, for which to give out 4.5V while undercharged is possible.  Though if they're undercharged, 3A is a bit too much for them to give out.  If you can post pictures of the top and bottom of the battery pack, I can take a look and say with a bit more certainty.  Then, recommending a charger won't be a problem.